# Adding data to database using MVC - with FK relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-entities

I have a database and I am using the Entity Framework with Linq 2 Enities. I am working with ASP.NET MVC 2.

I have a database with two tables as shown bellow:

```
Classifieds             Catergories
ID(PK)                  CatID(PK)
CatID(FK)               CatName
Desc
...
```

Obviously when the user adds a new classified and when they come to pick the category they don't want to see CatID's so my question is this. How do I let the user add a classified by selecting the CatName?

I am using strongly typed views. Restructuring the database is out of the question. Answer in C# please.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with this solution:

Controller:

```
    var Catergories = classifiedsRepositry.GetClassifiedsCategories().AsEnumerable();

    ViewData["CatID"] = new SelectList(Catergories, "CatID" , "Category");
```

View:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CatID, (SelectList)ViewData["CatID"],"--Pick A Category--")%>
```

And that is it dead simple and it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a drop-down exposing the category name, but using the Id as the value:

```
<%-- Using your Model has a list of Category objects set --%>
<%= Html.DropDownList("classified.Category.Id", new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "Name") %>
```

Your controller action might look something like:

```
public ActionResult Save(Classified classified)
{
   int categoryId = classified.Category.Id;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I have done something simmilar in MS Access so I thought that this was the way to go. I just didn't know how to implement it. 

Many thanks I will give it a go.

Comment: I can't do "Model.Catergories" in the selectList because my model is empty because I am adding data, I tried it and I am getting a null reference exception. Any idea on how to pass the catergories to the view I have tried ViewData.

Comment: Yeah it depends how you structure your Model. You should be able to use the ViewData dictionary, so in your controller:

ViewData["Categories"] = categories; //enurable list of category objs

and then in your view:
<%= Html.DropDownList("classified.Category.Id", new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["Categories"], "Id", "Name") %>

Answer (score 0):

Get the existing categories from the database (preferrably via a repository, but for brevity I just show the Linq to Entities query):

```
var db = new YourObjectContextImplementation();
var categories = db.Categories.AsEnumerable();
```

Forward these to your view via a view model. In your view, you output a form somehow to enable the user to add a classified. Instead of giving them a textbox (or select list) for the category Id, you give them a select list where the *value* is the id, but the *text/inner html* is the category name. That way, the user only sees the name, but your action gets an integer parameter passed to it.

---

UPDATE in response to comment:

I assume you are currently passing a new `Classified` object as view model, and then using the `EditorFor` helpers? All good, but you should probably wrap the `Classified` object in a specific view model, for example a `ClassifiedAddModel` as follows:

```
public class ClassifiedAddModel
{
    public Classified NewClassified { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> ExistingCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can instantiate and populate the `ClassifiedAddModel` object in the controller action, pass it along as the model to your view, and build the form using syntax like

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(Model.NewClassified.Description) %>
<%: Html.EditorFor(Model.Categories "CategoriesEditor") %>
```

where `"CategoriesEditor"` is the name of a custom view model that takes categories and renders a select list with them. The main point with the above example, however, is to show how you can access both properties on the `Classified` object, and all the existing categories.

Comment: I can't do "Model.Catergories" in the selectList because my model is empty because I am adding data, I tried it and I am getting a null reference exception. Any idea on how to pass the catergories to the view I have tried ViewData.